# C# SHA512 / Public Static String

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, cryptography

an annoying question today, i should know this but for the life of me i can't figure it out. I am trying to hash a password before querying the sql database. I have the hash code working fine however its inside a public static string:

```
     public static string GetCrypt(string text)
    {
        string hash = "";
        SHA512 alg = SHA512.Create();
        byte[] result = alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
        hash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
        return hash;
    }
```

I have two questions, one.. once it is hashed, how do i go about getting that result as when i try to access the variable "hash" it gives the error does not exist in current context. I suspect this is due to public and private classes?

Also, my other question, to have a more effective program, can i or is this already, a code where by i type it once, then can call it passing variables back and forth. sort of like, enter a password, it hashes, then passes it back.. then in another textbox pass new variable to the same hash code and get new hashed variable back?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: This code is *not* appropriate - you're converting arbitrary binary data (the hash) to a string using Encoding.UTF8. You should use Convert.ToBase64String (or hex).

Comment: Why aren't you using salted hashes? :(

Comment: @cdhowie: Is this for passwords?

Comment: @Јοеу: Yes; see the second line.

Comment: @SLaks: ah, indeed. Then the question should rather be why they aren't using bcrypt/scrypt instead of SHA-512.

Comment: SHA is too fast for passwords.  You should use PBKDFv2.  Also, security is _hard_; do not re-invent the wheel.  Use an existing, proven login system.

Comment: You need to learn how to use method return values.

Comment: As these are all answers in some form I'm going to create a community wiki answer.  Feel free to expand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use this method you would store the return value, like this:

```
string hashedString = GetCrypt(inputString);
```

Then use `hashedString` as appropriate.

However, you have some problems:

- The result of `alg.ComputeHash()` is not a UTF-8 encoded string, so `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` is very likely to throw an exception, and won't even do what you want.  Consider using `Convert.ToBase64String()` (or [convert the byte array to a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311165/501250)).
- You don't salt the input string, at least not within this method.  This means your database of passwords is vulnerable to [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks.  Consider using salted hashes or (better yet) an algorithm design specifically for hashing passwords, such as [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), [scrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) which is built in to the framework [itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).